# DevExpress MVC GridView and callbacks

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I've successfully added an MVC GridView to an ASP.NET MVC 4 application I'm writing.  I've bound it to data successfully, etc.

I've written some JavaScript to store the index field of the selected row to a hidden field...but to do this requires a callback.  The FocusedRowChanged client-side event is implemented in JS, and in this event I call GetRowValues for the grid.  like this:

```
  function OnReviewGridFocusedRowChanged() {
         ReviewAdGrid.GetRowValues(ReviewAdGrid.GetFocusedRowIndex(), "AdSequence",    OnReviewGridGetRowValues);
     }
```

This function requires a callback event:

```
function OnReviewGridGetRowValues(Value) {
    document.getElementById("ReviewID").value = Value;
}
```

The OnReviewGridGetRowValues is a callback event where the actual values of the requested fields are returned.

One problem - this callback is NOT being called.

Has anyone had any experience with this?  Do I have to do anything special in MVC to work with callbacks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have implemented the GridViewSettings.CallbackRouteValues. Check [this](http://www.devexpress.com/kbid=KA20010) KB Article.

Comment: If this helps, approve my answer.